# How to calculate interest rate between two dates with out put two dates parameter

Tags: t-sql

**Transaction table**

```
TransactionDate   Balance   
2014-03-30        50000
2014-04-05        2000
2014-04-10        1000
2014-04-20        25000
2014-05-05        10000
```

**Interest Rate table**

```
FromDate    ToDate      Rate
2014-02-28  2014-04-01  2.1%
2014-04-02  2014-04-15  2.2%
2014-04-16  2014-04-21  2.7%
2014-04-22  2014-05-02  2.8%
2014-05-03  2015-03-31  2.9%
```

SQL Query output required in below format

```
FromDate: 2014-04-01
ToDate:   2014-05-30
```

** Output table as below **

```
Balance FromDate    ToDate        Rate 

50000   2014-03-31  2014-04-01    2.1
50000   2013-04-01  2014-04-05    2.2
52000   2014-04-05  2014-04-10    2.2
53000   2014-04-10  2014-04-15    2.2
53000   2014-04-15  2014-04-20    2.7
78000   2014-04-20  2014-04-21    2.7
78000   2014-04-21  2014-05-02    2.8
78000   2014-05-02  2014-05-05    2.9
79000   2014-05-05  2014-05-30    2.9
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: You need to better explain where your desired output dates are coming from. for instance, I don't see half the desired dates in the transaction or interest rate tables you detailed. Keep in mind that the financial/accounting knowledge that seems obvious to you may be lacking from those of us you intend to ask for help.

Comment: Dear Nagaraj S,

Output table is what we needed from sql.That is example result only.
We have 2 table. one is transaction table and another is interest rate change table. Now what we require is how to handle a case when interest rate change in a interest rate master table but there is no transaction in transaction table. So we are not able to calculate interest amount on base of transaction rate change and actual transaction happen in transaction table. 

Early help appreciated.